# Why does the value of the hidden input filed gives me the same result alwayes?

Tags: php, html, css

First I'm beginner in php, second I'm trying to trace the value of the hidden input which is " the ID of the image in table products ", but whenever I click the delete button of any image, it always gives me the last id of the last image in my products table , and when I changed the input into text it prints the correct id but if I used it with POST it will not work .

Here is the codes :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$dataBase = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('HouseOfCake'); 
$PID = $_POST['PID'];
echo $PID ;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="Delete.php">   
<div class="container">   
<?php
$dataBase = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","" , "HouseOfCake"); 
?>
<div class="row text-center">         
<?php
$r=mysqli_query($dataBase,"SELECT*FROM Products");
while($Products=mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
?> 
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
<div class="card" name= <?php $Products['CakeID']; ?>>
<image src = <?php echo 
'data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($Products['Image']).'' ;  ?>  /> 
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title"> <?php echo $Products['Price']; ?> SR. </h4>
<p class="card-text"> Details.</p>
</div>
<div class="card-footer">
<input type="text" value= "<?php echo $Products['CakeID'] ?>"  name="PID" >
<input type = "submit" name="delete" value=" Delete Item." 
 style="width:250px" >           
</div> 
</div>
</div>      
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share the code as part of the question itself. Avoid posting the code in the comment section. Once you copy the code, format the code using the "{ }" (Code sample) option in the editor

Comment: Here's a link to [edit] your question. And __never__ post code in comments.

Comment: Please edit your original question and put the code into a code tag.

Comment: @DioneiMiodutzki .. I did , thank you and i apologize for the mistake .

Comment: @IncredibleHat .. It worked , thank you so much for you help .. and thank you all, i really appreciate it .

Comment: Glad you got that sorted out. There are ways to submit multiple fields of the same name, but given your need to delete just one item, it would just confuse matters to treat them as arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clean up what you are doing, so its easier to understand, you have this in a nutshell:

```
<form>
while {
   <inputs>
}
</form>
```

What this will do is submit ALL those inputs to PHP. And since each one of the inputs in the `while` have the same name, PHP will only use the 'last one received'.

You want to have your flow like this:

```
while {
   <form>
   <inputs>
   </form>
}
```

That way each form only submits the inputs defined inside of it (not all of them on the page).

---

So to recap with your code, you would want to have multiple forms on the page as such:

```
<?php while($Products=mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>
    <form method="POST" action="Delete.php">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $Products['CakeID'];?>" name="PID">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Item." style="width:250px">
    </form>
<?php }?>
```